# how to solve this Problem with google-assistant-sdk?

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

Has anyone got a solution for this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 5, in 
from googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk import main
File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 22, in 
import grpc
File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/**init**.py", line 22, in 
from grpc import _compression
File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in 
from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of regular text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: it looks like your libc version is not up-to-date. What sort of platform are you running on?